# Onclick of submit button should display a table containing list of file names in a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

First I will select the year & Month and on click of "Download" button,it is trying to run a download script.

Then,all the files will get downloaded in this directory /usr/local/ndt-files/year/month(/usr/local/ndt-files/2015/09).Onclick of download button,now I want to display the file names of this given directory in a table.Here the directory name is dynamic.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone please help me out ...

**HTML**

```
<form id="download" method="post" action="/download">
    <center> <span class="mandatory" style="color:red">*</span>
        <label>Year :
            <select id="year" name="year">
                <option value="select year:" selected>Select year:</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        </br>
        </br> <span class="mandatory" style="color:red">*</span>

        <label>Month :
            <select id="month" name="month">
                <option value="select month:" selected>Select month:</option>
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="July">July</option>
                <option value="August">August</option>
                <option value="September">September</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="November">November</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </center>
</form>
```

**My index.js:**

```
router.post('/download', function (req, res, next) {

    var year = req.body.year;
    var month = req.body.month;
    var limit = req.body.files;


    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('views/downloadInput.txt');
    stream.once('open', function (fd) {
        stream.write(year);
        stream.write('\n');
        stream.write(month);
        stream.write('\n');
        stream.write(limit);
        stream.end();
    });

    child = exec("/usr/local/src/node-v0.10.35/nodeprograms/views/scriptformonth.sh",

    function (error, stdout, stderr) {

        if (!error) {

            console.log(stdout);

        } else {

            res.send(error);

        }
    });
});
```

Scriptformonth.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/divya/gsutil
export BOTO_CONFIG="/root/.boto"


# To download .tgz files from mlab
#Reading lines in file.txt
File=/usr/local/src/node-v0.10.35/nodeprograms/views/downloadInput.txt

{
read YEAR
read MONTH
read FILES
} < $File

if [ $MONTH == "January" ]
then
    MONTH=01
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "February" ]
then
    MONTH=02
    DAY=28
elif [ $MONTH == "March" ]
then 
    MONTH=03
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "April" ]
then
    MONTH=04
    DAY=30
elif [ $MONTH == "May" ]
then 
    MONTH=05
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "June" ]
then 
    MONTH=06
    DAY=30
elif [ $MONTH == "July" ]
then 
    MONTH=07
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "August" ]
then 
    MONTH=08
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "September" ]
then 
    MONTH=09
    DAY=30
elif [ $MONTH == "October" ]
then 
    MONTH=10
    DAY=31
elif [ $MONTH == "November" ]
then 
    MONTH=11
    DAY=30
else
    MONTH=12
    DAY=31
fi

year=gs://m-lab/ndt/$YEAR/$MONTH/;

for((i=1;i<=$DAY;i++))
do
if [ $i == 1 ] || [ $i == 2 ] || [ $i == 3 ] || [ $i == 4 ] || [ $i == 5 ] || [ $i == 6 ] || [ $i == 7 ] || [ $i == 8 ] || [ $i == 9 ] 
then
  day=0$i/;
else 
  day=$i/;
fi

pathToDownload=$year$month$day

directory=/usr/local/ndt-files/$YEAR/$MONTH/$day/

command gsutil ls -l $entry  

if [[ ! -e $directory ]]; then
    mkdir -p $directory
elif [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
    echo "$directory already exists "
fi

TOTAL=$(gsutil du $pathToDownload | wc -l)

if [ $FILES == "ALL"]
  then
    FILES=$TOTAL
fi

for files in $(gsutil ls -l $pathToDownload)/*;
    do
      echo $files
      gsutil cp $files $directory
      COUNT=$(find $directory -type f | wc -l)
      echo "Count : " $COUNT
if [ $COUNT -eq $FILES ]
   then
      break
   fi
      done   
done
```

Comment: What's inside `scriptformonth.sh` file?

Comment: I had edited the code

Comment: I think it will be much much easy to write it in simple JavaScript, rather than executing such things. Really. It's going to be only a few lines of code.

Comment: Currently the script is running fine.Now I'm trying to display the list of all file names of a folder in a table.How can achieve this ?

Comment: Here the folder name is dynamic./usr/local/ndt-files is common for any directoty,only the year,month varies for each directory.I'm writing the selected year and month into a file "views/downloadInput.txt".

Comment: This goes to bash scripts, and it's pretty complicated for no reason. I can't help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96252/discussion-between-gangigunta-divya-and-andrey-popov).